# Modal Popup to use Menu template

Tags: joomla-4.x, templates, joomla-5.x

I have a modal button on my component list page which displays details of the record in a popup modal window.  My problem is I want the modal popup to use the same template set in the menu item for the list screen.  ie. my default template is "Cassiopeia Standard" but my menu item for the list view is set to "Cassiopeia Alternate".  When I click on the modal button, my popup window utilises the default and not the one set to the menu.  I have seen mention of using a parameter to indicate what template/style you want but was wondering if there's an easier way.
Any suggests how to get this to work as I want it?

Updated:
This is how I generate a modal button using a helper.  In the tmpl file all I need to do is echo the returned html which displays the button.  As you can see I'm getting the template_style_id from the active menu item but was hoping there might be an easier way.

```
class GamodalHelper
{
    /**
     * Set up modal button
     * @param   string $type - type of function (task or view)
     * @param   string $controller - form controller file to use recordform.php
     * @param   string $field - field used in the url
     * @param   mixed  $value - of the field to match in the url
     * @param   string $layout - tmpl layout file to use
     * @param   string $modname - name of the modal window so is unique should there be more than 1 on a page
     * @param   string $button - type of button to display (info, success, warning etc)
     * @param   string $label - text to go on the button if required
     * @param   string $title - title of the modal to display
     * @param   string $icon - icon image to show on button
     * @param   string $name - name that this record is relating to if required
     *          example $actionBtn = GamodalHelper::setupModalButton('view', 'resreqform', 'id', $this->item->id, 'modalact', 'myActModal', 'info', 'Action', 'COM_MYCOMPONENT_ACT_TITLE', $icon, $name);
     *          then echo $actionBtn; // where you want the button
     * @return  string  html string for the button
     */
    public static function setupModalButton($type, $controller, $field, $value, $layout, $modname, $button, $label, $title, $icon, $name)
    {
        $menuitem = Factory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
        // modal form
        $link = self::getHTTPQuery(null, $type, $controller, $field, $value);
        $link = self::getHTTPQuery($link, null, null, 'tmpl', 'component');
        $link = self::getHTTPQuery($link, null, null, 'layout', $layout);
        $link = self::getHTTPQuery($link, null, null, 'mstyle', $menuitem->template_style_id);
        $modalparams = array(
                        'url' => 'index.php?'.http_build_query($link, '', '&amp;'),
                        'title'      => Text::sprintf($title, $name),
                        'closeButton'=> true,
                        'modalWidth' => 40,
                        'bodyHeight' => 35,
                        'viewHeight' => 40,
                        'backdrop'   => 'static'
                        );
        $modalname = 'modal-'.$modname.$value;
        $html = '<a class="btn btn-'.$button.'" href="#'.$modalname.'" data-bs-toggle="modal">';
        $html .= '<i class="'.$icon.'" title="'.Text::sprintf($title, $name).'"></i> '.Text::_($label).'</a>';
        
        $html .= HTMLHelper::_('bootstrap.renderModal', $modalname, $modalparams);

        return $html;

    }

    /**
     * Build the HTTP query array
     * @param array of the http query if the http query already prepared and we want to add more
     * @param string view or a task
     * @param string control method to be used
     * @param string reference indicator
     * @param string/int reference string or id
     * @return array
     * @ hint - this is used with http_build_query($query_string, '', '&amp;') to build a clean url
     */
    public static function getHTTPQuery($existQ = null, $viewTask = 'view', $contModel = 'motion', $ref = 'id', $linkId = 0)
    {
        if ($contModel == 'article') {
            $compName = 'com_content';
        } else {
            $compName = 'com_mycomponent';
        }
        if (!$existQ) {
            $query_string = array();
            $query_string['option'] = $compName;
            $query_string[$viewTask] = $contModel;
            if ($ref) {
                $query_string[$ref] = $linkId;
            }
        } else {
            $query_string = $existQ;
            $query_string[$ref] = $linkId;
        }

        return $query_string;
    }

}
```